# iOSDropDown: Type 'UIResponder' has no member 'NSNotification'

Tags: swift, xcode

After updating to Catalina, and `pod update` I get a error

> Type 'UIResponder' has no member 'NSNotification'

This is for [iOSDropDown](https://github.com/jriosdev/iOSDropDown)

```
if isSearchEnable && handleKeyboard{
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in
            if self.isFirstResponder{
            let userInfo:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo! as NSDictionary
                let keyboardFrame:NSValue = userInfo.value(forKey: UIResponder.UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey) as! NSValue
            let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
            self.keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height
                if !self.isSelected{
                    self.showList()
                }
            }

        }
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in
            if self.isFirstResponder{
            self.keyboardHeight = 0
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You will now use `keyboardWillShowNotification` on `UIResponder` directly as mentioned [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder?changes=latest_minor) under **Type Properties**,

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil, queue: nil)
```

**Note:** As the error is inside an external library, you can either `fork` the library, fix the issue and point to your forked version in your `podfile`. OR, you can opt to do the changes on your local machine but it will be overridden everytime you will do `pod update`.

Comment: When try to change to your suggestion I get error: `'keyboardWillShowNotification' has been renamed to 'NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow'` and then: `Replace 'keyboardWillShowNotification' with 'NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow'`

Comment: I think, something weird is happening in your code causing this `error`. You can try this line of code in a fresh project. This will work with the updated version of `Xcode/Swift`.

Comment: Weird. I have reinstalled Xcode, and still the same error.. Do I need to delete the external library?

Comment: @PerNil Not yet! Did you create a fresh project and just tried above line of code?

Comment: Yes, and that worked fine. I ended up removing the external library, and deleting all code belonging to it, and then reinstalling the library. Everything works fine now. Thankfully there was just a few lines of code in use from that library

Comment: Glad it helped.